# simple match query with Elastica QueryBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I try lot of thing for executing a simple Match value request in ElasticSearch with PHP - Elastica library (FosElasticaBundle). But nothing run. Do you have a idea for run correctly this kind of code :

```
$match = new Match();
$match->setFieldQuery('product.price', 2);
$match->setFieldOperator('product.price', 'AND');
$query->setQuery($match);
```

I'm also trying this form :

```
   $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
   $fieldQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
   $fieldQuery->setFieldQuery('age', 'I am a title string');
   $fieldQuery->setFieldParam('age', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
   $boolQuery->addShould($fieldQuery);
   $query = $boolQuery;
   return $this->find($query);
```

No error return but nothing result. I just want this kind of request

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE price = 2;
```

How can do that with FosElasticaBundle ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the more convienient way of doing it but it works (you surely found a way to do it anyway) :

```
$price = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$price->setField("price","2");
$product = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$product->setField("_index","product");

$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
$boolQuery->addMust([$price, $product]);
$query = new \Elastica\Query($boolQuery);
```